# Using variable in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am attempting to extract `Smith` from `name` into `lastName`.

```js
function reggie(){
  var name = "JohnSmith";
  var first = "John";
  var regExp = new RegExp("(?:"+first+")(w+)", "gi");
  var lastName = regExp.exec(name);
  //Logger.log(lastName); // in google apps
  console.log(lastName);
}
reggie()
```

Comment: `w` matches `w`, you need `\\w` and then `Logger.log(lastName[1])` (but check if there is a match first)

Comment: Ah. Indeed it was `\\`. Thanks @Wiktor. Its still not matching but at least getting there

Comment: `var regExp = new RegExp("(?:"+first+")(\\w+)", "gi")` matches your `JohnSmith` string perfectly. Though you do not need the non-capturing group. Use `new RegExp(first+"(\\w+)", "gi")`. Actually, GAS RegExp has trouble with non-capturing groups sometimes.

Comment: got it. thanks again